# How to sort JSON array elements in descending order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In my **index.html**, I receive data from server which is in this order:

```
[
  {id: 1, keyOne: valueOne, keyTwo: valueTwo},
  {id: 2, keyOne: valueOne, keyTwo: valueTwo},
  {id: 3, keyOne: valueOne, keyTwo: valueTwo},  
  {id: 4, keyOne: valueOne, keyTwo: valueTwo}
]
```

I want to sort this in descending order, like:

```
[
  {id: 4, keyOne: valueOne, keyTwo: valueTwo},
  {id: 3, keyOne: valueOne, keyTwo: valueTwo},
  {id: 2, keyOne: valueOne, keyTwo: valueTwo},  
  {id: 1, keyOne: valueOne, keyTwo: valueTwo}
]
```

I have tried a number of ways from Stackoverflow but couldn't find a perfect match. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 5):

This is easy to do using the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method of arrays:

```js
const input = [
    {id: 1, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"},
    {id: 2, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"},
    {id: 3, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"},
    {id: 4, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"}
];

let sortedInput = input.slice().sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);
console.log(sortedInput);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note the usage of the [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method, invoking `slice()` is equals to invoke `slice(0)` to make a shallow copy of the original array. This way, when `sort()` is invoked it won't mutates the oiriginal `input` array.

Comment: Note that sorts also happen "in place," so the `input` variable will get modified as well. See [mdn - sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, updated to don't touch the original input. Anyway, he don't say anything about not mutating the input.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
my_array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.id > b.id) return -1;
    else if (a.id < b.id) return 1;
    else return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const JsonArray= [
    { id: 1, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"},
    { id: 2, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"},
    { id: 3, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"},  
    { id: 4, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"}
];

let JsonReversedArray= JsonArray.reverse();

console.log(JsonReversedArray);
```

Reverse the order of the elements in an array of object

but this will not work in this case

```
const JsonArray= [
    { id: 1, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"},
    { id: 5, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"},
    { id: 3, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"},  
    { id: 4, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"}
];
```

as u see here the reverse method reverse your array if your id are already in order so :

```
let JsonReversedArray= JsonArray.sort((a,b) => b.id - a.id);
```

this one will be correct for this case