# sort method not working properly in JavaScript / React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sorting

I wanted to sort my Array by Date in ActivityDate but it is not sorting anything.

Its an Array with Objects and ActivityDate is a Field of every Object. If you look at the output on the end you can see a Date that should be first in the log but it is still at the end as it is concated with Array1.

```js
const dummy = "2020-06-01T22:00:00.000Z";

const Array1 = [{"activitydate":"2020-06-01T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":8076,"time":120,"userid":138,"remark":"freigeschaltet","zkub":" ","status":0,"status_color":"000000","comment":"","project_name":"IT - Exchange Server"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-01T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":null,"time":60,"userid":138,"remark":"dddd","zkub":"B","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":null},{"activitydate":"2020-06-02T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":null,"time":228,"userid":138,"remark":"test\n","zkub":"Z","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":null},{"activitydate":"2020-06-03T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7651,"time":240,"userid":138,"remark":"test\n","zkub":" ","status":0,"status_color":"000000","comment":"","project_name":"ProFrame"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-03T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":null,"time":120,"userid":138,"remark":"testy reload","zkub":"B","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":null},{"activitydate":"2020-06-03T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":8198,"time":120,"userid":138,"remark":"start\n","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"JXM-CE-80A Zentralelektrik"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-05T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":8064,"time":60,"userid":138,"remark":"xchng","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"Motor 992 B6T"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-23T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7534,"time":456,"userid":138,"remark":"tst","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"IT - Exchange Server"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-24T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7348,"time":150,"userid":138,"remark":"kekw\n","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"ERB-UL"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-25T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7327,"time":235,"userid":138,"remark":"teschting 26.06\n","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"ERB2-H"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-27T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7651,"time":456,"userid":138,"remark":"Unlocked EIntrag\n\n","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"ProFrame"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-27T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7651,"time":456,"userid":138,"remark":"test","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"ProFrame"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-29T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7651,"time":456,"userid":138,"remark":"wie oft muss ich clicken?","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"ProFrame"}]
const Array2 = [{"activitydate":"2020-06-01T22:00:00.000Z","name":"Pfingstmontag","hourstype":"H","state":1}]

const ArrFinal = Array1.concat(Array2).sort((a, b) => Date.parse(new Date(...a.activitydate.toString().split("-")[2])) - Date.parse(new Date(...b.activitydate).toString().split("-")[2]))

console.log(JSON.stringify(ArrFinal))
console.log(dummy.split("-")[2])
```

Comment: Please don't "hide" your code/snippet. And for your next question: Part of creating a [mcve] is to remove anything that isn't directly involved in the question/problem. The only relevant property of `Array1` is `activitydate`. The other properties only force us to scroll.

Comment: Mashing all in one line is not always a good idea. You have a typo in your `( )` which isn't a problem in this case, but maybe in your next question. Storing your dates in separate variables would have made the misplaced `)` quite/more obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string in `activitydate` property is in format that can just be parsed automatically with `new Date(DATE_IN_STRING)`.

Just parse the date and sort by `Date` object.

```
const ArrFinal = Array1.concat(Array2).sort((a, b) => new Date(a.activitydate) - new Date(b.activitydate));
```

This works fine.

Comment: Yes thanks this seems to work. Less work that I have tried thanks

Answer (score 1):

more detail is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54152092/6643270)

Example code:

```js
const Array1 = [{"activitydate":"2020-06-01T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":8076,"time":120,"userid":138,"remark":"freigeschaltet","zkub":" ","status":0,"status_color":"000000","comment":"","project_name":"IT - Exchange Server"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-01T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":null,"time":60,"userid":138,"remark":"dddd","zkub":"B","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":null},{"activitydate":"2020-06-02T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":null,"time":228,"userid":138,"remark":"test\n","zkub":"Z","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":null},{"activitydate":"2020-06-03T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7651,"time":240,"userid":138,"remark":"test\n","zkub":" ","status":0,"status_color":"000000","comment":"","project_name":"ProFrame"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-03T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":null,"time":120,"userid":138,"remark":"testy reload","zkub":"B","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":null},{"activitydate":"2020-06-03T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":8198,"time":120,"userid":138,"remark":"start\n","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"JXM-CE-80A Zentralelektrik"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-05T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":8064,"time":60,"userid":138,"remark":"xchng","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"Motor 992 B6T"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-23T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7534,"time":456,"userid":138,"remark":"tst","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"IT - Exchange Server"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-24T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7348,"time":150,"userid":138,"remark":"kekw\n","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"ERB-UL"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-25T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7327,"time":235,"userid":138,"remark":"teschting 26.06\n","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"ERB2-H"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-27T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7651,"time":456,"userid":138,"remark":"Unlocked EIntrag\n\n","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"ProFrame"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-27T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7651,"time":456,"userid":138,"remark":"test","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"ProFrame"},{"activitydate":"2020-06-29T22:00:00.000Z","phaseid":7651,"time":456,"userid":138,"remark":"wie oft muss ich clicken?","zkub":" ","status":1,"status_color":"ff8000","comment":"","project_name":"ProFrame"}]

const Array2 =[{"activitydate":"2020-06-01T22:00:00.000Z","name":"Pfingstmontag","hourstype":"H","state":1}]

const ArrFinal = Array1.concat(Array2);

let resultArr = ArrFinal.sort((a,b) => b.activitydate - a.activitydate);
console.log(resultArr);
```